# Prevent tracking script on Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

Is there a way to not display the tracking script on a Landing Page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can leave out the `</body>` tag, which is what we did for one client that wanted their own SFMC link tracking (long story).

Comment: I just have AMPScript writing a single value for a response. But the SCRIPT tags are still added? I ended up just using the file Content Type Text File.